# Google play crash report

Tags: android

This is a crash submitted to google play by an user. My problem is that I really can't find the cause of crash in it. Personally, I haven't met this issue while testing my app so I can't reproduce steps which will take me to this error.

```
Build fingerprint: 'htc/cingular_us/m7:4.3/JSS15J/246232.3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '3'
pid: 4368, tid: 4672, name: Thread-23411 >>> com.ipcoop.subwaysurveillanceandroid <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr deadcab1
r0 00000000 r1 00000000 r2 00000000 r3 deadcab1
r4 69f98018 r5 00000000 r6 69f9802c r7 6a250a90
r8 6e109c70 r9 6c217f18 sl 6a1798f0 fp 6e109c84
ip 12404001 sp 6e109c30 lr 6a22c11b pc 6a22c108 cpsr 480f0030
d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 0000000000000009 d5 0000000000000006
d6 3f000000ba46df7f d7 00b5ef000000007f
d8 3f8000003f800000 d9 402000003f000000
d10 ffffffffffffffff d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 7269762065727550 d17 6e7566206c617574
d18 6f70203e2d203635 d19 6b646e2030203a73
d20 206d616572747320 d21 3a206d754e6d6163
d22 2030203820666620 d23 2030203420302030
d24 005e005d005c005b d25 0060005f005e005c
d26 0000000000000000 d27 0000000000000000
d28 0048004700460044 d29 004a0048004a0049
d30 0060006000600060 d31 0000000000000000
scr 68000013

backtrace:
#00 pc 00019108 /data/app-lib/com.ipcoop.subwaysurveillanceandroid-1/libstream.so
#01 pc 00019119 /data/app-lib/com.ipcoop.subwaysurveillanceandroid-1/libstream.so

code around pc:
6a22c0e8 bf004770 0002a652 44784801 bf004770 
6a22c0f8 000251ea f64cb508 f6cd23b1 220063ad 
6a22c108 f7fa701a bf00ea5e 4b07b508 681b447b 
6a22c118 f7fa4798 f7ffea56 f7faf97f f7ffea52 
6a22c128 f7fef9af bf00feb1 0002bf1c b5104b04 
6a22c138 4604447b 60033308 fa48f7ff bd104620 
6a22c148 0002a5fc b5104b04 4604447b 60033308 
6a22c158 fa3cf7ff bd104620 0002a5e4 b5104b04 
6a22c168 4604447b 60033308 fa30f7ff bd104620 
6a22c178 0002a5cc b5104b04 4604447b 60033308 
6a22c188 fa24f7ff bd104620 0002a5b4 447b4b02 
6a22c198 60033308 bf004770 0002a59e 447b4b02 
6a22c1a8 60033308 bf004770 0002a52e 447b4b02 
6a22c1b8 60033308 bf004770 0002a54e 447b4b02 
6a22c1c8 60033308 bf004770 0002a4f6 44784801 
6a22c1d8 47706800 0002be5a 447b4b02 6018681a 

code around lr:
6a22c0f8 000251ea f64cb508 f6cd23b1 220063ad 
6a22c108 f7fa701a bf00ea5e 4b07b508 681b447b 
6a22c118 f7fa4798 f7ffea56 f7faf97f f7ffea52 
6a22c128 f7fef9af bf00feb1 0002bf1c b5104b04 
6a22c138 4604447b 60033308 fa48f7ff bd104620 
6a22c148 0002a5fc b5104b04 4604447b 60033308 
6a22c158 fa3cf7ff bd104620 0002a5e4 b5104b04 
6a22c168 4604447b 60033308 fa30f7ff bd104620 
6a22c178 0002a5cc b5104b04 4604447b 60033308 
6a22c188 fa24f7ff bd104620 0002a5b4 447b4b02 
6a22c198 60033308 bf004770 0002a59e 447b4b02 
6a22c1a8 60033308 bf004770 0002a52e 447b4b02 
6a22c1b8 60033308 bf004770 0002a54e 447b4b02 
6a22c1c8 60033308 bf004770 0002a4f6 44784801 
6a22c1d8 47706800 0002be5a 447b4b02 6018681a 
6a22c1e8 47704610 0002be4e 44784801 47706800 
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---
```

Comment: it looks like a crash inside some native library you might be using.

Comment: Error from the NDK module, check the libraries you are using under libs->armeabi/armeabi-v7a/x86. Also [JNI, debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11088123/android-ndk-crash-log-too-big-to-find-error)

Comment: Am I able to get the file or line number where the error occures form this log? As I wrote, it's output from google play so I cannot use adb way of debuging.